# To exclude /usr/include/c++/4.3/ in compiling code with intel compiler

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11, icc

I am working on a cluster which has older version of intel compiler (11) and gcc (4.3).

I have installed a newer trial version of intel composer xe (with 14.0 compiler).  I have also installed gcc 4.9. Both the newer gcc and intel compilers are in my home directory (non-root)

I use C++11 in my codes, so obviously i use `-std=c++11` flag for compiling. I provide `-L`  and `-I` flags to include intel's includes and libraries in my makefile

When I try to compile my code with `icpc`, The compiler looks in `/user/include/c++/4.3/`.... path.

I tried to remove the path by setting `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`  to 
`/home/peter/intel/composerxe/include`.
But it still looks in the `/usr/include/c++`  path. Because of this, the old files in /`user/include/c++/4.3/tr1_impl/` ... are included and not the latest ones.

How do I stop the intel compiler to look into these paths and see the new ones. Now instead of intel compiler i use gcc4.9, what changes do i need to make ?

I tried adding `-nostdinc` flag for compiling, but no luck. It gives error as :

```
catastrophic error cannot open source file "iostream"
```

because 1st include header is iostream

Comment: for gcc, the switch `-nostdinc` may be what you want

Comment: i tried it. here is my content of make file : home/peter/intel/bin/icpc -o test -H -nostdinc -I/home/peter/intel/composerxe/include -L/home/peter/intel/composerxe/lib/intel64 -I/home/peter/boost_1_55_0 -std=c++11 test.cpp   ... It gives catastrophic error cannot open source file "iostream"

Comment: @pugs You should edit that information into your question.

Comment: Did you verify that iostream.h is located in the composerxe/include directory?

Comment: That is where the tricky part is. The standard headers are not present in ANY of the intel composer suite directory. icpc takes it from /usr/include/c++/ ..  Some specific headers such as math.h etc are present. but c++ headers are not present at all! (i did a quick find . -name "iostream" - no results). I just want icpc to not look in /usr/include/c++ and look into its own headers (if any). I dont know why intel compilers do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that intel shares its headers from already installed gcc in the system and takes the /usr/include  or usr/local/include  paths.

In my case, the operating system on our cluster is SUSE linux with gcc4.3 as default GNU compiler.

Now, the cluster management software is set such that two compilers (intel and gcc) cannot be loaded simultaneously (module intel version 11 and module gcc version 4.5)

After I did a `gcc --print-search-dirs`   I found out that the intel compiler inherits some common headers (iostream, etc) from existing gcc compiler (which is 4.3 in this case) and hence includes the old tr1_imple files and headers because of which I get errors in compiling c++11 code.

I did install gcc 4.9 in my home directory, but intel 14 has compatibility issues in including headers from gcc 4.9 and again this time weird compiler errors.

While using gcc 4.5 (`using module load gcc-4.5)` atleast got me to compile the code, I think the only solution to this problem would be to use gcc 4.7.2 and provide its include path since that was the first release with c++11 support ( not c++0x working draft)implementing a lot of c++11 features except concurrency.

One needs to know that Intel compilers do depend upon existing gcc compiler provided by the OS or installed by the user/root. Without that, they are pretty much of no use.

Cheers!